# How to display top most visited pages from Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to google analytics api and now I have a requirement to show top 5 most visited **pages** from our web site where google analytics is tracking. I need to retrieve top 5 page from this data using Jquery. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have used below script to just get the response from analytics api but i receive Login Required messsage. I do not want users to Authorize even once since i planning to use this information on my public facing website where users can't authorize.

```
function render(results) 
{
    if (!results.error.code) 
      {

      } else {
        outputToPage('There was an error: ' + results.error.message);
      }
}
function outputToPage(output) {
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
}
<div id="results"></div>

<!-- Replace RESOURCE with the path to the Google Analytics resource you're querying. -->
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?key={MY_KEY}&callback=render"></script>
```

Comment: I found a way of doing this using this article [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/devguide#access). I have tried using both methods from JavaScript tab and I am getting Login Required error when making request to google analytics data. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Anybody has done this before, please help me.

Comment: Can you post the query that you used to get the 5 most visited pages?

Comment: Please see my code in original post. I have also tried to use Hello Analytics sample and it generates the same error for me.